# NPM : update specific package without all dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm

In my project, I would like to update a specific package and its dependencies without updating all the dependencies of the project.

Here's how I do it.
First I install my project on the basis of the lock.
npm ci install packages in function of the package.lock.json. This way, I am sure to install the right version of dependencies.

```
npm ci
```

In my project I want to update fontawesome package with the latest version. the current version is 5.6.3 and I need the latest 5.7.2.

```
npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-pro@latest
```

Then I make a diff of my lock file and then surprise all my packages are updated. Not only the Fontawesome dependencies but also package like Babel or others. In addition, a majority of the packages have been downgraded.

Here an part of my lock file:
[image]

You can see my fontawesome package is updated but the package below is downgraded.

Why all dependencies are updated?
Why my packages are downgraded?